# How to get graph's namespaces in rdflib

Tags: python, rdflib

I've loaded an RDF file in Python, using rdflib:

```
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse ( "foaf_ex.rdf" )
```

the `*.rdf` defines a number of prefix/namespace pairs (e.g., `foaf:`) and I know they come into `g` because they're still there when I print `g.serialize()`.

My question is, is there an easy way to go get `"foaf:Person"` resolved from `g`, i.e., turned into `"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"`? getting an `URIRef` straight from the initial prefixed URI would be even better, but it would help anyway if I might get at least the full URI string.

Comment: http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/graph.html#Graph.namespaces. AFAIK, `foaf:` is predefined in some sense.

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav. foaf is predefined, but that's just an example, I need to retrieve custom namespaces. Graph.namespaces returns something, but I don't know how to use it, I've tried g.namespaces() [ 'foaf' ], says TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself to this old question, with the experience gathered meanwhile.

rdflib has a `NamespaceManager` class, the `Graph` object has a namespace_manager property, which can be passed to the a [`from_n3()`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/util.html) function, and the latter does what I need:

```py
def from_n3(s, default=None, backend=None, nsm=None):
    r'''
    Creates the Identifier corresponding to the given n3 string.

        >>> from_n3('<http://ex.com/foo>') == URIRef('http://ex.com/foo')
        True
        >>> from_n3('"foo"@de') == Literal('foo', lang='de')
        True
        >>> from_n3('"""multi\nline\nstring"""@en') == Literal(
        ...     'multi\nline\nstring', lang='en')
        True
        >>> from_n3('42') == Literal(42)
        True
        >>> from_n3(Literal(42).n3()) == Literal(42)
        True
        >>> from_n3('"42"^^xsd:integer') == Literal(42)
        True
        >>> from rdflib import RDFS
        >>> from_n3('rdfs:label') == RDFS['label']
        True
        >>> nsm = NamespaceManager(Graph())
        >>> nsm.bind('dbpedia', 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/')
        >>> berlin = URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin')
        >>> from_n3('dbpedia:Berlin', nsm=nsm) == berlin
        True

    '''
```

I've developed an extended version of NamespaceManager, the [`XNamespaceManager`](https://github.com/Rothamsted/agri-schemas/blob/6be711849c9b822007b7d39977bfa6ffca35891d/lib/etltools/utils.py#L52), which makes it simple to access this and other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Method `namespaces()` returns a generator so:

```
ns_prefix = 'foaf'
for ns_prefix, namespace in g.namespaces():
    if prefix == ns_prefix:
        print(namespace)
```

The `namespace` variable contains a `URIRef` object.

Comment: yes, it seems that's the way to go at raw level. I've used from_n3() (see my answer), which basically uses namespaces() but after having converted it into a dictionary. No idea why they do it, it doesn't seem faster than an explicit loop.